# Mobile Safari Now Playing

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari

I have been searching all morning. Anyone know if it's possible to get the Now Playing song of an iOS device from a web app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I am not familiar in safari but I found this guides on that

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Dashcode_UserGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/MakingDualPlatformWebApp/MakingDualPlatformWebApp.html

Comment: Could you include a relevant snippet from the link you posted? A link by itself isn't a complete answer.

Comment: Thanks George this uses a data source. I am trying to find an API objects to get the name from the device.